# Fantasy book: girl and her familiar frog, cat and fish escape their witch jailor and search for who they are

Tags: story-identification, books

It is a single book story about a girl who, along with a fish, a cat, a frog and maybe some other familiars, escapes the witch who was holding them captive.

The fish had a pearl in its mouth, the frog a stone on its head, the cat had something in its paw and the girl, something in her stomach.

I don't remember much more than it being their journey to finding out who they really are and why the witch had captured them.

Comment: You've provided a few details but we could really use some more, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details. Help us to help you!

Comment: The Unlikely Ones by Mary Brown. I would post this as an answer, but I keep getting suspended for not doing it right.

Comment: The unlikely ones, that's it,  thank you sueelleker :)

Comment: @sueelleker, you can write it as an answer and mention what points in the question correspond to the actual facts in the book.

Comment: @sueelleker Please don't be afraid to post answers. All you have to do is **cite your sources** - if you copy and paste text from elsewhere, remember to mention where you got it from - and you'll be fine :-)